# Meaning of some symbols in classical guitar tablature

Tags: theory, sheet-music, tablature

I am trying to learn classical guitar by myself. In the tablature of Romanza, I came across a few symbols whose meaning I couldn't find. I have learned basic music theory, and I can understand the staff notation. I don't understand the top or bottom of the symbol of the staff and tablature, e.g.:

- What is the meaning of the 3 vertical lines connected with a horizontal line over the *tablature* (not over the staff). Does that refer to upward pluck?
- What is the meaning of CV 3 and CVII 6.
- Is there a good reference resource (or book) for where I can look up these symbols and their meaning?

[image]

Comment: I wonder why this music is expressed in 3/4 entirely covered in triplets, rather than being expressed in 9/8. Are there non-triplet 8th notes elsewhere in the score?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C may stand for capotasto, cejilla or cejuela depending on the language. It basically means using a single finger to hold multiple strings, the same as a barre. The V or VII are Roman numerals and refer to the fret and the 3 or 6 tell you how many strings to hold down. Sometimes the letter B for barre and a number for the fret is used, i.e. B5.

CV 3 means barre the top 3 strings at the 5th fret

CVII 6 means barre all 6 strings at the 7th fret.

As you can see, the TAB supports this.

As for the 3 vertical lines connected by a horizontal line in the TAB, those are 8th note triplets, just like in the standard notation above. Note the 3 above the horizontal lines indicating triplets instead of regular eighth notes.

Thanks to @ElementsInSpace, @Lazy and @EuroMicelli for providing info on the various terms in the comments.

Comment: You might want to include that the C stands for _capotasto_.

Comment: _Capotasto_ in English and various other languages refers to the device used to hold down the strings, the [_capo_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capo), while _barre_ as far as I know is about the guitarist's finger holding down multiple strings. Does this notation mean "use a mechanical device on these strings" or does it mean "use your finger to hold them down"? Since you mention both _capotasto_ and _barre_ in the same context, assuming that the "C" does indeed refer to a finger, is it just the notation for a barre or is there a difference between the two? In short, I'm confused. Help?

Comment: @terdon I did some searching online and found only references to a device that holds down the strings for capotasto but in this case there is clearly not a mechanical device used to hold the strings down and scores of performances available online attest to that. Here is an example at about 1:08: https://youtu.be/2EHW8c85i00 I’m far from an expert on classical guitar notation but in this context it refers to a barre.

Comment: …maybe @ElementsinSpace would like to chime in on this…

Comment: Don’t worry, *it is* just a barre notation. No capotasto implied. And I don’t remember for sure but I’m not convinced “C” stands for “capotasto”; I’ll see if I can find a reference.

Comment: I'm no expert, but according to some basic research, it is the same thing: _capotasto_ is an Italian word, _barre_ is French word. Both refer to: either using a mechanical device, or a finger, to hold down multiple strings.

Comment: Capotasto is italian and basically translates to "head fret" and means the nut. Barré notation allows both B and C, where the C *can* mean "capotasto", but also "cejilla", the spanish word for barré technique. In slighly older spanish scores we do also find the notation Cª, which does *not* fit "capotasto".

Comment: Ah, I see. I had learned “C” as meaning “cejilla” which is a word in Spanish for a barre (rarely used, it might depend on country; commonly I just call it “barra”). What I didn’t know is that “cejilla” and “cejuela”, both from “little eyebrows”, are themselves synonym of “capotasto” (valid in Spanish too, of Italian origin). So, depending on where the notation originated, it probably stands for “capotasto”, “cejilla” or “cejuela”, but they all mean the same thing.

Comment: I guess another edit is in order!

Comment: While the confusion seems to have been resolved, I would just point out that it isn't particularly odd for _capotasto_ to refer in some contexts to a particular device and in others to a technique; _mute_ comes to mind as another example of a device that is named for the thing it does.  But @Lazy doesn't _tasto_ mean "fingerboard" rather than "fret" (consider _sul tasto_ for a bowed instrument)?  In that light, I would read _capotasto_ the notational instruction as meaning "the head of the fingerboard [is temporarily at the specified fret]."

Comment: @phoog No, not really. Fret is not a particularly good translation here, but I do not know a better english word for the context. "Tasto" comes from "tastare", which means something like "to touch, to feel something with your fingers" (most likely from latin "tangere").

So in music "tasto" generally refers to *anything* that you touch to produce a sound, such as keys on pianos and stuff. The fretboard is not called "il tasto" but "la tastiera". So "sul tasto" rather means "at the touch". "At the fretboard" would be "sulla tastiera".

Comment: @EuroMicelli Not exactly, cejilla can mean the same as capotasto, but it (and the main form ceja) generally refers to something being "covered" (thus eyelid). So the term refers not only to the capotaster (device) and the nut, but also to the bridge. So sometimes "ceja" is used for a full barré and cejilla for a small barré where only the top strings are barred.

Comment: @Lazy why then is the bowing instruction _sul tasto_ rather than _sulla tastiera?_  It seems to imply that _tasto_ is at least a partial synonym for _tastiera._  (Furthermore, for sense 2(b) at https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tasto/, I suppose that "fret" is precisely the right translation, notwithstanding the fact that I've never seen a fret made of ebony or any other kind of wood, but the attribution of only "indicative" function suggests that the definition was written by a non-musician.)

Comment: @phoog As I said, you find both "sul tasto" *and* "sulla tastiera". And also I said, "sul tasto" would literally mean "at the touch". I think the main reason you predominantly see "sul tasto" is because is less complicated to say than "sulla tastiera".